# SWT check if shell exceeds screen bounds

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

I have a button that opens a shell in my application, which displays a number of checkboxes, along with 2 buttons at the bottom. The problem is that it can get cut off due to its height being too big.

The solution I want is to add the contents of the shell to a ScrollableComposite, which doesn't work, because the shell just expands in height, so the composite's scrollbars don't do anything.

I figured the best way would be to calculate if the shell exceeds the screen bounds, but I don't understand how its coordinates really work. The shell's parent is a shell, so `Shell::getBounds()` is supposed to return the coordinates *relative to the display*, but I think I need the shell's bounds *relative to the monitor* (which I can get through `Shell::getMonitor()`) in this case.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the shell size based on the monitor size rather than the bounds.

This is what the Eclipse Launch Configuration Dialog uses to make sure it is not too big:

```
protected void setShellSize(int width, int height) {
    Rectangle bounds = getShell().getMonitor().getBounds();
    getShell().setSize(Math.min(width, bounds.width), Math.min(height, bounds.height));
}
```

Comment: I am going to accept this answer, thanks Greg. However, I don't know if it's application specific, but getBounds() for the shell in question didn't return the global (=relative to the display) coordinates, but the coordinates relative to the window.

Comment: Shell.getBounds is relative to the parent shell if there is one and the display if not. This code is not using that getBounds.

Comment: This assumes though that the shell is aligned to the top left corner / is maximized. In my case, the shell is always located near the bottom of the screen and it needs to take all the necessary height, if it's too big. The solution was something like what you suggested, but I use setSize taking the shell's position into account, and I get its position from the button (with `toDisplay`), under which it is shown.

Comment: Testing here the shell location is adjusted to make the full shell appear if possible.